# Upgrade pod-identity-webhook mutating webhook configuration for EKS 1.22 upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS 1.21 cluster which I am trying to upgrade to 1.22. While upgrading resources with deprecated API versions I found that I have a mutating webhook configuration called `pod-identity-webhook` that is using deprecated APIVersion `admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1`.

It seems that `pod-identity-webhook` is managed by AWS, will this be upgraded by AWS as part of cluster upgrade process or I have to upgrade it?
If I have to upgrade it then does anyone have any idea on how to do it since I am not able to find any upgrade doc on google.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it's not a red herring? Have a look at https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/issues/164